# sql insert into, select, where statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to copy all row from hk_room table into hk_history except row with rStatus = '-' OR rStatus='Long Stay' and rStatus = 'Check Out'.

'-' is the default value for rStatus attribute.

I have tried these two query:

```
INSERT INTO hk_history
(rNo,rStatus,bs,bq,hk,ds,dq,pc,twl,fm,amt,db,mw,hkR,fo_R,svR,rDate)
SELECT rNo,rStatus,bs,bq,hk,ds,dq,pc,twl,fm,amt,db,mw,hkR,fo_R,svR,rDate
FROM hk_room1;
WHERE rStatus <> '-';
```

or

```
INSERT INTO hk_history
(rNo,rStatus,bs,bq,hk,ds,dq,pc,twl,fm,amt,db,mw,hkR,fo_R,svR,rDate)
SELECT rNo,rStatus,bs,bq,hk,ds,dq,pc,twl,fm,amt,db,mw,hkR,fo_R,svR,rDate
FROM hk_room1;
WHERE rStatus = 'Long Stay' AND rStatus = 'Check Out';
```

[but I got this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysgCI.png)

Comment: `hk_room1;` `;` ends the statement.

Comment: Incase the above itsn't clear.  Remove the`;` after `hk_room1` if you want the where clause to execute as part of the insert.

Comment: is that the most cryptic set of column names you could come up with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a semicolon before the `where` in the first query:

```
INSERT INTO hk_history
    (rNo,rStatus,bs,bq,hk,ds,dq,pc,twl,fm,amt,db,mw,hkR,fo_R,svR,rDate)
    SELECT rNo,rStatus,bs,bq,hk,ds,dq,pc,twl,fm,amt,db,mw,hkR,fo_R,svR,rDate
    FROM hk_room1;
    -------------^
    WHERE rStatus <> '-';
```

You need to remove it.

To achieve this:

> want to copy all row from hk_room table into hk_history except row
>   with rStatus = '-' OR rStatus='Long Stay' and rStatus = 'Check Out'.

Just use a single statement:

```
INSERT INTO hk_history
    (rNo,rStatus,bs,bq,hk,ds,dq,pc,twl,fm,amt,db,mw,hkR,fo_R,svR,rDate)
    SELECT rNo,rStatus,bs,bq,hk,ds,dq,pc,twl,fm,amt,db,mw,hkR,fo_R,svR,rDate
    FROM hk_room1
    WHERE NOT (rStatus = '-' OR 
               rStatus = 'Long Stay' and rStatus = 'Check Out'
              );
```

You can also phrase that as:

```
    WHERE rStatus <> '-' AND
          (rStatus <> 'Long Stay' OR rStatus <> 'Check Out')
```

However, the previous version seems clearer for your intent.

Comment: I see, so the problem is the semicolon. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO hk_history
 (rNo,rStatus,bs,bq,hk,ds,dq,pc,twl,fm,amt,db,mw,hkR,fo_R,svR,rDate)
 SELECT rNo,rStatus,bs,bq,hk,ds,dq,pc,twl,fm,amt,db,mw,hkR,fo_R,svR,rDate
 FROM hk_room1
 WHERE rStatus IN ( '-', 'Long Stay' , 'Check Out')
 ;
```

This should help